# How to connect to Google API Adwords using REST API

Tags: python, curl, google-ads-api, apigee

I am trying to connect to google api using REST API URL so that I can integrate the same with Apigee. But when I tried the below I am getting 404 not found response. Please advice

```
import requests

headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer access token',
'developer-token': 'xxxxyyyy',
}

response = requests.get('https://googleads.googleapis.com/v2/customers/<customerid>/campaigns', headers=headers)
```